# App.js GET url parameter and send to routes/index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here is my url: http://localhost:3000/?url=test

I'm running a Express so in my app.js I'm trying to get a the url parameter "test" send it to my routes/index.js

I'm sending a static variable no problem by using:

code in app.js

```
app.locals.url = 'a test string';
```

and receiving in my routes/index.js

```
var url;
url = req.app.locals.url;
```

Any idea how in app.js I can have:

```
app.locals.url = {the parameter "test" in the http://localhost:3000/?url=test}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to refer the query parameters in a false parameter. 
While using Express.js, we refer to the parameters sent with GET request in the following manner -

```
var url = req.query.url; //url is the parameter sent - localhost:3000/?url=www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

With express, you can use [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

```
req.query.url
// => "test"
```

A representation of the HTTP request is passed to the callback function of most methods.  This object will have property `query`, which will contain a property for each query string in the HTTP request.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  url = req.query.url;  // For http://localhost:3000/?url=test, val => 'test'

});
```

Comment: Can this be used in app.js?

Comment: So all I have to do in app.js is app.locals.url = req.query.url;

Comment: You can get the value you are looking for with `req.query.url`, as long as you are in the right context.